# useCallback and memoization

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

How the memorized callback function works? In some articles I read that the function is recreated if we do not use useCallback. But if it is recreated, should it be different from the prev version? In my code I didn't notice that there was a difference in callback functions.
**My question is: Why in both cases, my set size is 1?**

from off doc useCallback

> Returns a memoized callback.
>
> Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. useCallback will
> return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of
> the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to
> optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent
> unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

```
import { useCallback } from "react";

const dataSource = [
    {
        id: 1,
        model: "Honda",
        color: "red",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        model: "Mazda",
        color: "yellow",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        model: "Toyota",
        color: "green",
    },
];

const Car = ({ model, color, set, onCarClick }) => {
    const onClick = () => onCarClick(model, color);
    set.add(onCarClick);
    console.log(set.size);
    return (
        <div onClick={onClick}>
            Model: {model} Color: {color}
        </div>
    );
};

const CarsCallback = ({ cars, set }) => {
    const onCarClick = (model, color) => {
        console.log(model, color);
    };
    console.log("CarsCallback");
    return (
        <>
            {cars.map((car) => {
                return (
                    <Car
                        key={car.id}
                        set={set}
                        {...car}
                        onCarClick={onCarClick}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};

const CarsUseCallback = ({ cars, set }) => {
    const onCarClick = useCallback((model, color) => {
        console.log(model, color);
    }, []);
    console.log("CarsUseCallback");
    return (
        <>
            {cars.map((car) => {
                return (
                    <Car
                        key={car.id}
                        {...car}
                        set={set}
                        onCarClick={onCarClick}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <CarsCallback cars={dataSource} set={new Set()} />
            <CarsUseCallback cars={dataSource} set={new Set()} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What actually happens when useCallback is used?

Comment: **@Ramesh Reddy**, thank you, i add my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `CarsUseCallback` and `CarsCallback` was triggered once.

We can see the only one log of `CarsUseCallback` and `CarsCallback`.

If we re-render the `CarsUseCallback` and `CarsCallback`, we can see the size is `1` and `2`.

```
const CarsCallback = ({ cars, set }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  console.log('CarsCallback');
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(2);
  }, []);
  // ...

};

const CarsUseCallback = ({ cars, set }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  console.log('CarsUseCallback');

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(2);
  }, []);
  // ...

}
```